# Let $W\subseteq\omega$ be an infinite c.e. set. Show that there is an infinite $X\subseteq W$ such that $X$ is computable.

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, computability

If I can prove that $X$ is c.e. and $\omega \setminus X$ is c.e. then I can prove that $X$ is computable by the theorem "Let $W \subseteq \omega$. Then $W$ is computable iff both $W$ and $\omega \setminus W$ are c.e". But I'm not able to proceed on how should I do this.

Comment: I've rolled back the question: the new title had nothing to do with the question, and additionally losing the old title made the body of the question nonsensical. (I've also fixed the formatting of the title.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a computable surjection $f : \omega \to W$.

Define $V = \{f(x) \mid x \in \omega$ and $\forall y < x (f(y) < f(x))\}$. Clearly, $V \subseteq W$.

Then $V$ is decidable. For to decide whether $v \in V$, simply keep generating $f(x)$ for $x = 0, 1, \ldots$ until we come up with the first output $\geq v$. If this is $v$, then $v \in V$; otherwise, $v \notin V$.

And $V$ is infinite. For if $f(x) \in V$, take the smallest $y$ such that $f(y) > f(x)$; then $f(y) \in V$.